# Flutter RawKeyboardListener Buggy

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app that scans barcodes using a 2D bluetooth scanner. The app is in production and has been working fine, now with the recent SDK updates from Flutter, the `RawKeyboardLister` i use to to listen for the inputs from the scanner does not work anymore once the soft/virtual keyboard has been opened.

There are some instances on the app where a user needs the keyboard to input characters but after  they do and they move on to a screen that does more scanning, the listener only registers `RawKeyUpEvent` and no longer registers `RawKeyDownEvent`.

Here is my code:

```
class ScannerFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final StreamController scanController;

  ScannerFragment(
      {Key key, @required this.child, @required this.scanController})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScannerFragmentState createState() => _ScannerFragmentState();
}

class _ScannerFragmentState extends State<ScannerFragment> {
  final FocusNode focusNode = new FocusNode();

  final List<String> scannedCharacters = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<BaseProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext _, BaseProvider provider, Widget __) {
        if (!provider.keyboardMustComeToView)
          return _buildRawKeyboardListener();

        return widget.child;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRawKeyboardListener() {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onKey: _handleKey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  void _handleKey(RawKeyEvent key) {
    var x = key.character;
    var u = key.logicalKey;
    var y = locator<BaseProvider>().keyboardMustComeToView;
    print("${key.character}");
    if (key.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
      RawKeyEventDataAndroid data = key.data as RawKeyEventDataAndroid;
      //keycode of key event (66 is return)
      if (data.keyCode == 66 || data.flags == 136) {
        locator<DirectechProvider>().setProcessingScan = false;
        print("terminate: ${scannedCharacters.join()}");
        widget.scanController.add(scannedCharacters.join());
        widget.scanController.done;
        scannedCharacters.clear();
        return;
      }
      if (key.character != null) {
        if (!locator<DirectechProvider>().processingScan)
          locator<DirectechProvider>().setProcessingScan = true;
        scannedCharacters.add(key.character);
      }
    }
  }


  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Here is my flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G6020, locale en-ZA)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

--EDIT--

After dealing with a screen that has a textfield and then returning to a scanning screen with no textfield. This is the issue I face, there is a small soft input thingy that floats at the bottom of my screen which captures what I actually scanned but the keyboardlistener reads incorrect thing.

[image]

N.B. When i minimise the app and open it again, the scanning works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone comes across this issue in future, the solution is not to use Microsoft Swift Keyboard with RawKeyboardListener. Rather use Gboard.

Answer (score 1):

On what version of flutter did it stop working?
For now I would suggest to rollback to that version. This will allow you to continously develop for production and users can continue to receive updates.

Write this command:

```
flutter downgrade "version_number"
flutter clean
```

However for the long term, can you please post the name of the package that you are using to receive streams from the bluetooth scanner?

**[EDIT]**

Try this command then:

```
flutter version 1.17.4
```

Then when it asks you to confirm whether you wish to downgrade press on **y**.

After it's done run:

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: I have been trying to rollback to an older version of flutter using those commands, notably version `1.17.4` but for some reason the whole thing returns back to version `1.22.0`.  I am using the following packages:
`
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` for `RawKeyboardListener` and `import 'dart:async';` for `StreamController scanController`

Comment: please note that the commands I've provided for you are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of flutter. But for now, it's a solution

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I managed to rollback to that version as per your instructions above but the issue still persist unfortunately. At this point, I do not know what to do anymore, thank you for your assistance

Comment: Take a look at this package to listen for keyboard notifications: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_utils